# Leer CDATA en XML con C#

Tags: c#, xml

tengo un inconveniente, tengo un programa que lee un XML y saca unos datos, pero ultimamente los XML que se estan cargando vienen con CDATA, y no puedo leer el contenido, la pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo leer el contenido del CDATA dentro de un XML usando C#

Comment: Como estas tratando de leerlo?

Comment: Has preguntado a google ? Una simple busqueda me devuelve varios enlaces [link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93df8772-0eaf-4ac7-9918-aa39f4c8af23/reading-cdata-content-from-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c?forum=csharplanguage), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027845/parse-cdata-from-xml-in-c-sharp), [link3](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/461393/Read-CDATA-from-XML). Pero como no adjuntas el codigo ni el XMl poco te puedo ayudar

Comment: la lectura del XML la hago normal con xmlElement y xmlNodeList llamos las etiquetas normal, pero la parte del CDATA es la que se me dificulta

Comment: XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

                        xDoc.Load(ruta);// Ruta donde se guardo el archivo cargado

                        XmlNodeList FactElect = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("fe:Invoice");
                        foreach (XmlElement nodo in FactElect)
                        {

Comment: pon tu codigo de como lo lees y el xml para ayudarte